# Does the Node.js debugger send SIGINT/SIGTERM when exiting with Ctrl-C?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

While running tests, I'm running into a situation where a server I've started isn't closed when exiting the Node.js debugger, and it seems like this is causing the debugger to not stop listening on port `5858`.

```
debug> 
(To exit, press ^C again or type .exit)
debug>
$
```

But then...

```
$ node debug test.js
< Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::5858
<     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
<     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
<     at Agent.Server._listen2 (net.js:1259:14)
<     at listen (net.js:1295:10)
<     at net.js:1405:9
<     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:11)
<     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
connecting to 127.0.0.1:5858 ... ok
```

When you have Node.js debugger running, and you hit `Ctrl-C` twice, what does it to do the process you were debugging? Does it send `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT` or `SIGKILL` or something else?

And why doesn't the debugger detach sometimes? Resulting in port `5858` still being in use.

Comment: Just hit this issue too.

Answer (score 0):

open your activity monitor & search for node process after that quit or force quit that node it will kill running node process. after that you can run node again freshly with node debug test.js.